# How to delete user connections to my app?

Tags: gmail, gmail-api

My app, which is unverified, has over 100 users. As per Google's policies, unverified apps with over 100 users will simply stop working. We are trying to verify the app, but cannot, since we cannot show functionality, because we have over 100 users. Does someone know how I can delete / remove all user connections from my app via the GMail API? Thanks!